# setting value doesn't work when iterating array by pointer increment

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

In example1, setting element is done by `[]` operator and getting element is done by pointer increment `*(data++)`, and it seems to work well. In example2, on the other hand, both setting and getting element are done by pointer increment and seem not work. From this comparison, I can guess that pointer increment seems not compatible with element setting.

Could you explain why this happens and how can fix this problem?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){
  {
    std::cout << "=== example 1 ===" << std::endl; 
    int* data = new int [6];
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
      data[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
      std::cout << *(data++) << std::endl; 
    }
  }
  {
    std::cout << "=== example 2 ===" << std::endl; 
    int* data = new int [6];
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
      *(data++) = i;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
      std::cout << *(data++) << std::endl; 
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
=== example 1 ===
0
1
2
3
4
5
=== example 2 ===
60753
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: In the second piece of code, after the first for: Where do you think `data` will point? And where will it point when you increment it the next time?

Comment: ahh, I understand

Comment: On a side note: both examples are leaking memory, as you are not `delete[]`’ing the array allocated by `new[]`. Both examples are losing the original pointer to that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `data` and then using it again as if you hadn't changed it. Just declare a new variable

```
    std::cout << "=== example 2 ===" << std::endl; 
    int* data = new int [6];
    int* ptr = data;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
      *(ptr++) = i;
    }
    ptr = data;             // move ptr back to the beginning of data
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
      std::cout << *(ptr++) << std::endl; 
    }
```